# How to create a shortcut to run an EXE while simultaneously executing a command line?

Tags: ngrok

I am trying to create a shortcut for ngrok.exe where the command line "ngrok tcp 3389" would be automatically introduced and excuted
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMZDE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5v6y.png)
And here it is after excuting [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8FDE.png)

I tried creating this .bat [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4mhe.png) file but it doesn't stick, meaning it executes the command then exits immediately

Comment: Add a `pause` as your last line of the batch file. The command you entered likely finished (i.e. the process exited), and the command window has no further reason to remain open. There are VB flags for running the command with the window in different ways (e.g. background, open-until-close, ...), but you'd be leaving batch behind at that point. Further, anything after the `ngrok.exe` will be arguments to `ngrok`, so you just want `...\ngrok.exe tcp 3389`

Comment: [For the future](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), *do not* post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)